# Trouble using Invoke-Command with ScriptBlock and -ArgumentList

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I'm new to powershell and can't figure why I get the following error

Invoke-Command : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'D:\Deploy\file.zip'.
At D:\source\Scripts\Build-Deploy\Build-Deploy\ServersDeploy.ps1:105 char:5

- Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -ScriptBlock {
- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand

This is the script being run

```
params([string[[]]$servers, [string]$dest_package_path, [string]$src_package_path,[string]$deploy_script)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -ScriptBlock {
    param($dest_package_path,$src_package_path,$deploy_script) 
    Write-Output "Destination path = $dest_package_path"
    Write-Output "Copying zip $src_package_path to the destination host"
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $dest_package_path
    Write-Output "Directory Created"
    Copy-Item -Path $src_package_path -Destination $dest_package_path -Force        

    Write-Host "Copying remote deploy scripts to the destination host"
    Copy-Item -Path $deploy_script -Destination $dest_package_path -Force
} -ArgumentList $dest_package_path $src_package_path $deploy_script
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you separated the arguments with spaces instead of a comma. That makes them new arguments to `Invoke-Command`.

`-ArgumentList` a single parameter that takes an array:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -ScriptBlock {
    # Stuff
} -ArgumentList $dest_package_path,$src_package_path,$deploy_script
```